# sending a message from Gmail from a chosen account

Tags: gmail, stock-email-app

I have 3 Gmail accounts but whenever I reply my message is sent from my original account even if I change the from address and hit send immediately.

I have a HTC Sensation

Comment: Are you using the GMail app? I have a Samsung Galaxy S4, with 2 GMail accounts on it, but I can't change the FROM field using the GMail app. This is not my main mail app though; I use Kaiten, which allows me to change the FROM field.

Comment: I used to have this same problem.